# How can I create a Laravel 8 project without the default boilerplate?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm creating a Laravel 8 project with this command:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname`

I've noticed that it brings in lots of files I won't use, such as a `User` model, `bootstrap.js`, migrations like `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`, translations under `resources/lang/en` and so on.

Is there a way to create a Laravel project without all this?

Comment: consider Lumen https://lumen.laravel.com/

Comment: How is this related to Composer itself? If you are not content with the default files Laravel ships, why not ask the maintainers for a cleaner setup?